# How to access image details i.e. GPS data and Luminous intensity in python

Tags: python, image, machine-learning

I am trying to make a machine learning classifier in python on images. For doing this I need to access image details like GPS location, timestamp and luminous intensity. I have tried to use matplotlib.pyplot.imread to import the image. This gives me only the RGB information which I also need to use but I cannot access the other specs.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
image = plt.imread("test.jpg")
```

How can I access these other specs from the image in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called EXIF metadata, not always present in all images. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif

Doing a quick google search for a python library that reads EXIF from images: https://pypi.org/project/ExifRead/

Then you could still use matplotlib for loading the RGB data.

Hope this helps